# Cargar opciones AsyncSelect en React desde Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, select

quiero cargar las opciones a mostrar en un select desde firebase, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
    <AsyncSelect 
        cacheOptions 
        defaultOptions 
        loadOptions={getBrands} />

    var brands = []

    const getBrands = async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve => {
            db.collection("cars").get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                
                    [doc.data()].forEach(brand => {
                        if(!brands.includes(brand.marca)) {
                            brands = [...brands, brand.marca]
                        }
                    })
                
                return resolve(brands)
            });
        });
    }))
}
```

No entiendo que puede estar mal, entiendo que debo devolver una promesa, pero ni siquiera veo que se llame a la funcion.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un par de cosas que creo que serian buenas corregir:

1. `[doc.data()].forEach(brand =>` no tiene mucho sentido ya que estás haciendo un array de un solo elemento y luego usando `forEach` en vez de usar el elemento directamente.
2. Si quieres obtener el campo `marca` de tu documento puedes usar `doc.get("marca")`.
3. Si estás utilizando `async` (pareciera que lo intestaste por el
   `getBrands = async () =>`), puedes dejar de lado los callbacks
   (`.then()` `.catch()`) y utilizar `async/await`.

Tomando esto en cuenta :

```
 const getBrands = async () => {
  try {
    let brands = [];
    let querySnapshot = await db.collection("cars").get();
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const marca = doc.get("marca");
      if (!brands.includes(marca)) {
        brands = [...brands, marca]
      }
    });
    return brands;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return []
  }

}
```

UPDATE:

Hasta ahora me doy cuenta que estás pasando el handle de la función y no invocándola.

<strike>Esto es un llamado asincrónico, la función se va a resolver de manera inmediata cuando cuando la invocas en el render del prop (cuando haces `loadOptions={getBrands}`), esto significa que los datos aún no van a estar listos y tu elemento va a renderizar con un prop que no tiene los datos. Te recomiendo manejar esto como un estado de react siguiendo el ciclo de vida que sugiere [la documentación](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).</strike>

Te dejo este ejemplo para que puedas entender lo que sucede:

```js
//Con esta funcion voy a simular tu pedido a Firestore
//Voy a simular que hay una ridiculamente mala conexión
//y el pedido tardó 10 segundos
const simularAsync = (data, callback) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(data);
  }, 10000);
};

//Esta funcion es un equivalente de tu función getBrands
const getBrands = async() => {
  console.log("Se inicia el pedido a firestore");
  brands = await simularAsync(["Nike", "Adidas", "New Balance"], (data) => {
    console.log("Hasta ahora se resolvió el pedido a Firebase, pero es muy tarde");
    console.log("Se obtuvieron los datos: ", data, " pero tu componente AsyncSelect no los recibió");
    brands = data;
  });
  return brands;
}


/*Esta variable recibe el valor de getBrands, simulando el prop de tu componente de react:
<AsyncSelect 
    cacheOptions 
    defaultOptions 
    loadOptions={getBrands} <=Este prop
/>
 */
let loadOptions = getBrands();
console.log("Valor que pasaste a loadOptions:", loadOptions);
```

Comment: consigo que los valores lleguen al array de brands, pero no se cargan en el AsynSelect...

Comment: No, porque el pedido es asincrónico, lo que estás pasando como prop a tu componente `AsyncSelect `  es el resultado inmediato de tu función que no corresponde a los de la base de datos porque se tiene que hacer el pedido y "traer" los datos de la misma. Te actualicé la respuesta para que tengas una idea de qué está pasando.

Comment: Me esta cogiendo los datos, los intenta mostrar en el select, pero el texto me sale en blanco, es decir, va a firebase, coge los 3 registros y me muestra 3 opciones pero en blanco

Comment: En ese caso supongo que el problema que tienes está en tu elemento  `AsyncSelect `

Comment: Si puedes editar tu respuesta incluyendo este código podría ayudarte.